# MediaWiki: Default template per namespace for created pages

Tags: templates, namespaces, mediawiki

Is there a way to have a default (something I were to assign) template to a namespace that a new page is created in?

For instance, you create a new namespace called "Test Namespace".  How do I assign that Namespace a "default" template.  Now, from now on, when I create new pages in the "Test Namespace" inherit the template assigned to "Test Namespace".

Is there a way to do this?

Note: I'd rather not use an extension for this, but in the long run, I might have to, but please give both suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the extension option, consider [Extension:NewArticleTemplates](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aNewArticleTemplates) and the other options linked there.